# How can my Page request to join a group I am personally a member of?

Tags: facebook

I have been made admin of a facebook page representing my local church. I would like the Page to request membership of several local community groups but I am myself a member of all these groups and whenever I go to such a group the only option I have is to post as myself...I can't apply to join as my page if I'm already a member.

These are groups which do allow pages as members. How can I request membership for my page?

Answer (score 1):

This should be how to do it:
https://www.facebook.com/help/103763583048280/

Please note the notification at the top of the article:
"If you can't join a group as your Facebook Page, it might be because the group admins don't allow Pages to join their groups."

This means that if one of the local community groups (if not all) don't allow pages to join, you actually can't do it at all. The only solution then is to ask the community if they will allow it.

For classic pages where you're already joined as a profile/person this should be the way to do it:

1. Go to that particular group and leave with your profile.
2. Join again as a page.
3. Visit the group and under the timeline, you should see the "interact as" menu.
4. Then you click on your profile and reload the group

You should see that you have to join it again as your profile.

If this does not work, the group simply does not allow pages to join. Which can still be the case as pointed out by the Facebook documentation:

"Group admins might not allow Pages to join their groups.
"

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for a classic page. The URL you specify links to this one https://www.facebook.com/help/215443548960829 but for a classic page, this only works for groups you _own_/admin. For groups I'm just a member of, there is no way to requet membership

Comment: Edited the answer to include how to do it with a classic page, I suspect that if you can't choose the page to join the group they simply aren't allowing pages to join

Comment: Have you tested that link? When I try it (https://www.facebook.com/groups/search/groups_home?q=cheese) I do not see the same thing, groups have join/visit options and it doesn't give you the option which profile to use, it uses the currently selected profile.

Comment: I have already determined the group allows pages to join - my Modern page can request to join. But you cannot "select to  interact as..." a Classic page.

Comment: I have edited the answer yet again. This time, could you try to follow the steps to unjoin as yourself? Then joining as your page and then interact as to get your profile in it as well?